# Optimization bailouts warning when using lodash in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

> x component depends on 'lodash'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can
> cause optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

This is how i use lodash in my x component.ts

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
....
....

foo(){
 this.myObject = _.mapValues(this.myObject , () => true);
}
```

How do I get rid of this warning?

Comment: see https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies it literally tells you how, but agree with @pbachman - if you can switch to `lodash-es`, then the root cause for warning will go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the CommonJS variant of lodash, you could use [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) (ES modulized).

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider not using lodash at all. From this article [10 Lodash Features You Can Replace with ES6](https://www.sitepoint.com/lodash-features-replace-es6/) we have below features you can replace with ES6

1. **Map, Filter, Reduce**

*These collection methods make transforming data a breeze and with near universal support. We can pair them with arrow functions to help us write terse alternatives to the implementations offered by Lodash:*

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], function(n) { return n * 3; });
// [3, 6, 9]
_.reduce([1, 2, 3], function(total, n) { return total + n; }, 0);
// 6
_.filter([1, 2, 3], function(n) { return n <= 2; });
// [1, 2]

// becomes

[1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 3);
[1, 2, 3].reduce((total, n) => total + n);
[1, 2, 3].filter(n => n <= 2);
```

*It doesn’t stop here, either. If we’re using a modern browser, we can also use `find`, `some`, `every` and `reduceRight` too.*

2. **Head & Tail**

*Destructuring syntax allows us to get the head and tail of a list without utility functions*

```
_.head([1, 2, 3]);
// 1
_.tail([1, 2, 3]);
// [2, 3]

// becomes

const [head, ...tail] = [1, 2, 3];
```

*It’s also possible to get the initial elements and the last element in a similar way:*

```
_.initial([1, 2, 3]);
// -> [1, 2]
_.last([1, 2, 3]);
// 3

// becomes

const [last, ...initial] = [1, 2, 3].reverse();
```

*If you find it annoying that reverse mutates the data structure, then you can use the spread operator to clone the array before calling reverse:*

```
const xs = [1, 2, 3];
const [last, ...initial] = [...xs].reverse();
```

3. **Rest and Spread**

*The `rest` and `spread` functions allow us to define and invoke functions that accept a variable number of arguments. ES6 introduced dedicated syntaxes for both of these operations:*

```
var say = _.rest(function(what, names) {
  var last = _.last(names);
  var initial = _.initial(names);
  var finalSeparator = (_.size(names) > 1 ? ', & ' : '');
  return what + ' ' + initial.join(', ') +
    finalSeparator + _.last(names);
});

say('hello', 'fred', 'barney', 'pebbles');
// "hello fred, barney, & pebbles"

// becomes

const say = (what, ...names) => {
  const [last, ...initial] = names.reverse();
  const finalSeparator = (names.length > 1 ? ', &' : '');
  return `${what} ${initial.join(', ')} ${finalSeparator} ${last}`;
};

say('hello', 'fred', 'barney', 'pebbles');
// "hello fred, barney, & pebbles"
```

4. **Curry**

*Without a higher-level language such as `[TypeScript][5]` or `[Flow][6]`, we can’t give our functions type signatures, which makes currying quite difficult. When we receive curried functions, it’s hard to know how many arguments have already been supplied, and which we’ll need to provide next. With arrow functions, we can define curried functions explicitly, making them easier to understand for other programmers:*

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
var curriedAdd = _.curry(add);
var add2 = curriedAdd(2);
add2(1);
// 3

// becomes

const add = a => b => a + b;
const add2 = add(2);
add2(1);
// 3
```

*These explicitly curried arrow functions are particularly important for debugging:*

```
var lodashAdd = _.curry(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
var add3 = lodashAdd(3);
console.log(add3.length)
// 0
console.log(add3);
// function (a, b) {
// /* [wrapped with _.curry & _.partial] */
//   return a + b;
// }

// becomes

const es6Add = a => b => a + b;
const add3 = es6Add(3);
console.log(add3.length);
// 1
console.log(add3);
// function b => a + b
```

*If we’re using a functional library like `lodash/fp` or `ramda`, we can also use arrows to remove the need for the auto-curry style:*

```
_.map(_.prop('name'))(people);

// becomes

people.map(person => person.name);
```

5. **Partial**

*As with currying, we can use arrow functions to make partial application easy and explicit:*

```
var greet = function(greeting, name) {
  return greeting + ' ' + name;
};

var sayHelloTo = _.partial(greet, 'hello');
sayHelloTo('fred');
// "hello fred"

// becomes

const sayHelloTo = name => greet('hello', name);
sayHelloTo('fred');
// "hello fred"
```

*It’s also possible to use rest parameters with the spread operator to partially apply variadic functions:*

```
const sayHelloTo = (name, ...args) => greet('hello', name, ...args);
sayHelloTo('fred', 1, 2, 3);
// "hello fred"
```

6. **Operators**

*Lodash comes with a number of functions that reimplement syntactical operators as functions, so that they can be passed to collection methods.*

*In most cases, arrow functions make them simple and short enough that we can define them inline instead:*

```
_.eq(3, 3);
// true
_.add(10, 1);
// 11
_.map([1, 2, 3], function(n) {
  return _.multiply(n, 10);
});
// [10, 20, 30]
_.reduce([1, 2, 3], _.add);
// 6

// becomes

3 === 3
10 + 1
[1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 10);
[1, 2, 3].reduce((total, n) => total + n);
```

7. **Paths**

*Many of Lodash’s functions take paths as strings or arrays. We can use arrow functions to create more reusable paths instead:*

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }, 4] };

_.at(object, ['a[0].b.c', 'a[1]']);
// [3, 4]
_.at(['a', 'b', 'c'], 0, 2);
// ['a', 'c']

// becomes

[
  obj => obj.a[0].b.c,
  obj => obj.a[1]
].map(path => path(object));

[
  arr => arr[0],
  arr => arr[2]
].map(path => path(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

*Because these paths are “just functions”, we can compose them too:*

```
const getFirstPerson = people => people[0];
const getPostCode = person => person.address.postcode;
const getFirstPostCode = people => getPostCode(getFirstPerson(people));
```

*We can even make higher-order paths that accept parameters:*

```
const getFirstNPeople = n => people => people.slice(0, n);

const getFirst5People = getFirstNPeople(5);
const getFirst5PostCodes = people => getFirst5People(people).map(getPostCode);
```

8. **Pick**

*The pick utility allows us to select the properties we want from a target object. We can achieve the same results using destructuring and shorthand object literals:*

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

return _.pick(object, ['a', 'c']);
// { a: 1, c: 3 }

// becomes

const { a, c } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

return { a, c };
```

9. **Constant, Identity, Noop**

*Lodash provides some utilities for creating simple functions with a specific behavior:*

```
_.constant({ 'a': 1 })();
// { a: 1 }
_.identity({ user: 'fred' });
// { user: 'fred' }
_.noop();
// undefined
```

*We can define all of these functions inline using arrows:*

```
const constant = x => () => x;
const identity = x => x;
const noop = () => undefined;
```

*Or we could rewrite the example above as follows:*

```
(() => ({ a: 1 }))();
// { a: 1 }
(x => x)({ user: 'fred' });
// { user: 'fred' }
(() => undefined)();
// undefined
```

10. **Chaining & Flow**

*Lodash provides some functions for helping us write chained statements. In many cases, the built-in collection methods return an array instance that can be directly chained, but in some cases where the method mutates the collection, this isn’t possible.*

*However, we can define the same transformations as an array of arrow functions:*

```
_([1, 2, 3])
 .tap(function(array) {
   // Mutate input array.
   array.pop();
 })
 .reverse()
 .value();
// [2, 1]

// becomes

const pipeline = [
  array => { array.pop(); return array; },
  array => array.reverse()
];

pipeline.reduce((xs, f) => f(xs), [1, 2, 3]);
This way, we don’t even have to think about the difference between tap and thru. Wrapping this reduction in a utility function makes a great general purpose tool:

const pipe = functions => data => {
  return functions.reduce(
    (value, func) => func(value),
    data
  );
};

const pipeline = pipe([
  x => x * 2,
  x => x / 3,
  x => x > 5,
  b => !b
]);

pipeline(5);
// true
pipeline(20);
// false
```

**Conclusion**

> Lodash is still a great library, and this article only offers a fresh perspective on how the evolved version of JavaScript is allowing us to solve some problems in situations where we would have previously relied on utility modules.
> Don’t disregard it. Instead, next time you reach for an abstraction, think about whether a simple function would do instead!

Answer (score 0):

Below Solution work for me:

> Step 1: `npm install --save lodash-es`
>
> Step 2: Whitelist CommonJS dependency - `angular.json`

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["lodash"]
    }
  }
}
```

Find more details here: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies